# how to get which point (x,y) contributes to which cells (Rho,Theta) in accumulator array of hough transform in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, hough-transform

I have a **binary image which contains only some points**. I have applied **"hough" method** of **Matlab** on that image and got an *accumulator array*. Now i have selected the maximum value of the **cell (rho, theta)** of accumulator array.

Suppose the **max value is 15** which is contained by **cell (0.5,30)**. From my understanding it means that **15 curved lines** has gone through (0.5,30) space and that why it's **vote count is 15**.

> *These curved lines also have gone through others (rho, theta) space and also voted there.*

**My problems are these**

1. **Which 15 points contribute to the (0.5,30) space in the accumulator array?**
2. **If any point (x,y) is a voter of (0.5,30) space, at which (rho, theta) space, (x,y) has also voted?**

*How could i know these question's answers in **Matlab**?* Codes will be very helpful.

*Any concept or algorithm will be also helpful.*

Comment: @Benoit_11
@ Ratbert

Comment: Hough trafo is not intend to answer these questions. You would need to implement a second hough transform that answers your questions. This one you could run after the first hough transform has determined the max value.

Comment: Does this mean that i have to build my own hough transform method to get my answers? @ Steffen

Comment: You can not use the default hough transform for that. The information you seek vanishes when the points are added in the accumulator. You need an other method.

Comment: Does Matlab disclose their "hough" method's background code so that i can modify it to to track down of my information before it vanishes? 
Can i use this code? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Example:Hough_transform/MATLAB
@Steffen

Comment: Dont know. Before you do that. I would rather question the motivation behind your question. when hving rho and theta, you can also move along that line in the image and check the values in the image.

Comment: I have to vote down for point (x,y) from (rho, theta) space in accumulator array except in the max value where the point have already contributed.The (x,y) has to vote for only one (rho, theta) space.@Steffen